# R if statement loop applied the first element only

Tags: r, if-statement

I have a DF named x contains 2 variables hour and timeofday.

I do need to give 4 different values to timeofday variable according to the following rules :

```
if (x$hour>=0 & x$hour<6){x$timeofday<-"midnight"} else
  if(x$hour>=6 & x$hour<12) {x$timeofday<-"morning"} else
    if (x$hour>=12 & x$hour<18) {x$timeofday<-"afternoon"} else
    {x$timeofday<-"night"}
```

Unfortunately only the first rule "midnight" is applied to all conditions.

```
   timeofday hour
1   midnight    0
2   midnight    1
3   midnight    2
4   midnight    3
5   midnight    4
6   midnight    5
7   midnight    6
8   midnight    7
9   midnight    8
10  midnight    9
11  midnight   10
12  midnight   11
13  midnight   12
14  midnight   13
15  midnight   14
16  midnight   15
17  midnight   16
18  midnight   17
19  midnight   18
20  midnight   19
21  midnight   20
22  midnight   21
23  midnight   22
24  midnight   23
25  midnight    0
26  midnight    1
27  midnight    2
28  midnight    3
29  midnight    4
30  midnight    6
```

Your support is much appreciated, Thank you

Comment: try `ifelse()` it's vectorized.

Comment: @mtoto  :  I have tried ifelse()  then i got only last rule applied which is "night"                                                                                     ifelse(x$hour>=0 & x$hour<6,x$timeofday<-"midnight",ifelse(x$hour>=6 & x$hour<12,x$timeofday<-"morning",
    ifelse(x$hour>=12 & x$hour<18,x$timeofday<-"afternoon", (x$timeofday<-"night")))

Comment: there's typo's in your call, see solution for correct syntax.

Comment: I think you want to look into `?cut` - `cut(0:23, breaks=c(0,6,12,18,24), include.lowest=TRUE, labels=c("midn","morn","after","night")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by `mtoto` as well, `ifelse` is vectorized while `if` not. So this will be your solution:

```
x$timeofday<-ifelse(x$hour>=0 & x$hour<6,"midnight",
       ifelse(x$hour>=6 & x$hour<12,"morning",
              ifelse(x$hour>=12 & x$hour<18,"afternoon","night")))
```

Comment: Note that you don't necessarily need to use ifelse. You can simply write: `x$timeofday[x$hour>=0 & x$hour<6] <-"midnight"`, `x$timeofday[x$hour>=6 & x$hour<12] <-"morning"` and so on...

Comment: Also, the real point is that `if-statement` is used for [control flow](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Control.html) which means the portion of code inside of the if statement is evaluated only if the condition is true (the first value of the logical vector, if a vector of conditions is passed, as in this case), otherwise is evaluated the portion of the code in the `else`.

Comment: Yes actually the `ifelse` it's probably in this case not the better way to do element assigment. But as he was asking a way to correct that statment, that was the solution

Comment: @adiana: sure nothing wrong here ;)  what I'm more worried about is that ifelse function is very often confused as a replacement of if-statements and vice-versa... but they do different things!