# If statement in R uses only first condition to all of the statements. Why?

Tags: r, function, if-statement, rstudio, lubridate

The below Function  which is using to count time in some ranges uses only one condition to all of the statements. Why?

I have been trying to use "any" function to vectorize this statements but it still doesn't work

```
data <- data.frame(date1=c(as.POSIXct("2016-01-15 13:04:00"),
as.POSIXct("2016-02-25 15:04:00"),as.POSIXct("2016-02-25 15:04:00"),
as.POSIXct("2016-02-25 15:04:00"),as.POSIXct("2012-10-10 17:50:00"),
as.POSIXct("2016-04-14 13:15:00"),as.POSIXct("2016-07-13 08:32:00"),
as.POSIXct("2016-07-13 08:35:00"),as.POSIXct("2016-07-13 08:36:00"),
as.POSIXct("2016-08-09 11:57:00")),

date2=c(as.POSIXct("2018-12-20 16:49:00"),as.POSIXct("2018-12-20 16:50:00"),
        as.POSIXct("2018-12-20 16:50:00"),as.POSIXct("2018-12-20 16:54:00"),
        as.POSIXct("2019-01-11 16:52:00"),as.POSIXct("2019-01-22 11:09:00"),
        as.POSIXct("2019-01-22 11:46:00"),as.POSIXct("2019-01-22 11:26:00"),
        as.POSIXct("2019-01-22 11:18:00"),as.POSIXct("2019-01-22 11:19:00")),

Mid.Category=c("A12","BN1","BN1","BN1","A06","A06","A06","A06",
"A06","A06"),

true_time=c(14983.77,12223.78,12223.78,
                            12223.85,31975.05,14179.92,
                            12925.25,12924.87, 12924.72,
                            12543.38))




data$Mid.Category <- as.character(data$Mid.Category)
str(data)



#################### FUNCTION ###############################

function_SLA <- Vectorize(function(date1,date2){

library(lubridate)


dni_wolne <- c("2018-01-01","2018-01-06","2018-04-01","2018-04-02",
              "2018-05-01","2018-05-03","2018-05-20","2018-05-30",
              "2018-08-15","2018-11-01","2018-11-11","2018-11-12",
              "2018-12-25","2018-12-26","2019-01-01","2019-01-06",
              "2019-04-21","2019-04-22","2019-05-01","2019-05-03",
              "2019-06-09","2019-06-20","2019-08-15","2019-11-01",
              "2019-11-11","2019-12-25","2019-12-26")


if(data$Mid.Category %in% c("B06","B12","BN0","BN1")){


dates <- seq(from=date1,to=date2,"mins")
dates <- dates[which(weekdays(dates) %in% c("poniedziałek","wtorek",
"środa","czwartek","piątek","sobota")

                  & hour(dates) >= 8 & hour(dates) <22
                  & !(as.character(dates,format="%Y-%m-%d") %in% dni_wolne))]

dates <- length(dates)/60


} else if(data$Mid.Category %in% c("A06","A12","AN0")){

dates <- seq(from=date1, to=date2, "mins")

dates <- dates[which(hour(dates) >= 8 & hour(dates) < 22)]

dates <- length(dates)/60
}
return(dates)
}


)

data$wynik <- function_SLA(data$date1,data$date2)
```

Time that is counting based on this function has to be the same as true_time in data frame but it is true only for one condition in this function. Second condition is counting based on other statement

Comment: Looking at `help("if")` you will see the `if` function is intended to be used for program control flow, not for comparing longer vectors - "*cond: A length-one logical vector that is not 'NA'.  Conditions of
          length greater than one are currently accepted with a
          warning, but only the first element is used.*" You might have to loop over each and every value in `data$Mid.Category` so that you can compare 1 by 1, e.g. using `lapply` or an explicit `for()` loop.

Comment: If you want vectorized `if`, then [`ifelse`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.0/topics/ifelse). Or if you need "total" (all/some/none) logic, then [`all`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.0/topics/all) or [`any`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.0/topics/any).

Comment: Some further hopefully helpful discussion is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36515730/r-if-statement-loop-applied-the-first-element-only and here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54825426/how-to-use-conditional-statement-and-return-value-for-a-function-in-r An example of how to loop using an `*apply` statement is also here: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/33351/what-is-the-problem-with-the-condition-has-length-1-and-only-the-first-elemen

Comment: how to use sapply function ? This doesn't work with "sapply(data$Mid.Category, function(x) ... " :(